# how to have multiple counters in the same page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, counter, new-operator, countdown

I'm tryng to make multiple countdown timers to run together but I not know how to make this work... see my code to try understand..

```js
var interval;  // I want to have this variable unique for each timer...
    var minutes = 14;
    var seconds = 59;
 

    function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    alert(el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!");                    
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 59;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? '' : '');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? '' : '';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ':' + seconds + '' + second_text + '';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: This question kind of reminds me of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you scope down your question to what you really want to achieve? I'm not sure if you need help with the code inside `countdown` or outside of it.

Comment: Why do `interval`, `minutes` and `seconds` need to be global variables? Just declare them inside the function.

Comment: Ok, let me be a little more clear, what I need is a page that contains 12 timers, which start from 15 minutes and go down, each timer needs to have its own button to start and that works as a reset for the same.. (if it is already running, the time goes back to 15 min and counts down again).

Comment: What I already have, I made the page, I set up the layout, but when I go to the part of running the 12 together I don't understand the mechanics of saving data from a function while it's running and changing its data while everything works... the closest code that I found that would be the solution for this I put it in the topic... I tried to change change create variables, but I don't have much knowledge of javascript, so I came to ask for help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use array for this. And send time as args to function and clearInterval by index.

```js
var intervals = [];  
 

function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
    const i = intervals.length;
    intervals.push(setInterval(function() {
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {    
                clearInterval(intervals[i]);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 59;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? '' : '');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? '' : '';
        console.log( minute_text + ':' + seconds + '' + second_text + '');
        seconds--;
    }, 1000));
}

countdown(14, 50);
countdown(5, 17);
```

Comment: so this works but only in console? because I need to change the content of html like in <"el.innerHTML = minute_text + ':' + seconds + '' + second_text + ''; >

Comment: No. It works every where. Just change console.log on what you are need